# Am I able to use a users device sign in options to login to app?

Tags: android

I'm still new to App dev. I have have seen some apps that use the device pin/lockscreen pattern to authenticate the user without making the user sign in again. Is there an API for doing this? The only thing close that I can find is logging in with google. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if i am wrong. `You want something like if user is logined than you dont want to display login screen again`.

For that you have to follow this approach.

- Allow user to enter email and password in the input fields.
- Store them in shared_preference ( local android storage ) with `is_logined = true` as login status.
- Next time whenever you will come in this page, you will check weather user is logined if yes show different page else show login page.

Comment: Exactly. You put it much better than I could have

Comment: follow these steps you will learn a lot by creating this small application.

Comment: But have authenticate the user by their device pin or password when their is_logined = true

Comment: can you please make it clear, i think we cant get device_pin.

Comment: I think I got it figured out. Thanks for the help. So many people just down vote without helping at all.